# Cannot call function in view model from <content> element

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia, aurelia-dialog, aurelia-templating

When I click button `#btn1` or `#btn2` Save, the console says that:

```
Uncaught Error: save is not a function
    getFunction @ aurelia-binding.js:1971
    evaluate @ aurelia-binding.js:1565
    callSource @ aurelia-binding.js:4989
    (anonymous function) @ aurelia-binding.js:5013
    handleDelegatedEvent @ aurelia-binding.js:3211
```

But the outter button `#btn3` works fine. I also try `$parent.save()` in `#btn2` but it's not work. Any idea?

**app.html**

```
<create-location contact.two-way="contact" working-time.two-way="workingTime">
    <require from="dist/component/working-time"></require>
    <working-time title="Working Time" view-model.ref="workingTime"></working-time>
    <require from="dist/component/contact"></require>
    <contact title="Contact" phone="123" email="user@example.com" fax="123456" view-model.ref="contact"></contact>

    <button id="btn1" type="button" click.delegate="save()">Save (=>error<=)</button>
    <button id="btn2" type="button" click.delegate="$parent.save()">Save (=>error also<=)</button>
</create-location>
```

**create-location.html**

```
<template>
    <button id="btn3" type="button" click.delegate="save()">Save (=>it works<=)</button>
    <content></content>
</template>
```

**create-location.js**

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework'

export class CreateLocationCustomElement {
    @bindable contact;
    @bindable workingTime;

    save() {
        alert("save");
    }
}
```

---

**Update**
I tried Fabio's suggest and [it works](https://gist.run/?id=bd69d7b81db72ce2f158819113c88f2d).

*Another question*: Look at [aurelia dialog](https://github.com/aurelia/dialog), they call `testDelegate` function of view-model inside `<content>` element similar to my case. They don't use `view-model.ref`. I take a look at the source code but I don't find out where they process that call. Maybe I miss out some point or are there conventions here. Does anyone know how they do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the create-location's view-model in a property, using `view-model.ref`, and then use that property to call `save()`. Like this:

```
<create-location view-model.ref="createLocationVM" contact.two-way="contact" working-time.two-way="workingTime">
    <require from="dist/component/working-time"></require>
    <working-time title="Working Time" view-model.ref="workingTime"></working-time>
    <require from="dist/component/contact"></require>
    <contact title="Contact" phone="123" email="user@example.com" fax="123456" view-model.ref="contact"></contact>

    <button id="btn1" type="button" click.delegate="createLocationVM.save()">Save (=>error<=)</button>

</create-location>
```

Nevertheless, I think it would be better if you recreate the whole component. There's no need to use `<require>` inside the component's content, and perhaps you could put the second save button in the create-location's view.

Comment: Because create-location page is a pre-render page on server  and I want aurelia to take control to whole page on browser (to use binding, custom component, ...), so I create `create-location` component and use aurelia enhance feature ([view more here](https://gist.run/?id=bd69d7b81db72ce2f158819113c88f2d)). I wonder whether this is a proper way to do or not. Have you ever do something like this? Btw, take a look at [aurelia dialog](https://github.com/aurelia/dialog). They have a `testDelegate` function, but I don't know how can do that. They don't use `view-model.ref` at all.